# scriptsharp & jquery plugin : how to provide additional methods on plugin

Tags: script#

I create a jquery plugin with scriptsharp... how can I define additional methods, and access the options of the plugin?

As far as I can see, there is only one method available and the options are not stored with the elements?

e.g. I want to be able to write :

jQuery.Select("#myDiv").Plugin().somemethod();

in somemethod I want to access MyPluginOptions...

**update: 3 nov 2011:**
as far as I can see, the only option I have now, is to define the method as follows:

```
public static jQueryObject MyPlugin(object methodOrOptions, object parm1, object parm2 )
```

ok, first parameter, methodOrOptions is ugly, but probably the only way, due to the nature of javascript.
but then, I have to specify as many extra arguments, as any extra method would need. It' a pity I can't use params object[] here. (**update 4 nov:** no support for optional parameters as well...)

Still the whole pattern seems 'not right' to me, ok, due to difference between c# and javascript, but maybe scriptsharp compiler could help us, to overcome mismatch...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the samples? If I understand your question correctly this is pretty much all covered...

https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/master/samples/PhotoGrid/Plugins demonstrates writing an import library for an existing plugin (Lightbox and Isotope).

https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/master/samples/PhotoDemo/Gallery demonstrates writing a plugin that enables the following (a method + options type with method using the options object of course):

```
GalleryPluginOptions options =
    new GalleryPluginOptions("tags", tags,
                             "thumbsListID", "thumbsList",
                             "photoPanelID", "photoPanel",
                             "thumbnailTemplateID", "thumbnailTemplate",
                             "photoTemplateID", "photoTemplate");

jQuery.Select("#gallery").Plugin<GalleryObject>().Gallery(options);
```

This bit of code is in the method related to the options object:

```
public static jQueryObject Gallery(GalleryPluginOptions customOptions) {
    GalleryPluginOptions defaultOptions =
        new GalleryPluginOptions("count", 10,
                                 "photoService", new FlickrService());
    GalleryPluginOptions options =
        (GalleryPluginOptions)jQuery.Extend(new Dictionary(), defaultOptions, customOptions);
```

Comment: First, I'm talking about a real plugin, like your GalleryPlugin..
Your gallery plugin has only one method : Gallery( customOptions )
but supppose you want to have additional methods 
$("#mydiv").gallery( options ); => this creates the plugin

$("#mydiv").disablegallery();  // additional method on gallery plugin (needs to access options)
or
$("#mydiv").gallery("disable"); // this seems to be the new way of providing additional methods on jquery plugins

Comment: Couldn't you just add a string parameter to your plugin method - eg. Gallery(string operation) ... or even used a named enum and instead have Gallery(GalleryOperation operation)? Or I am missing something?

Comment: I can't seem to find a good solution to this...try to add params object[] parms to MyPlugin method, but static method of plugin does not accept it..